# injecting multiple services in a single controller .NetCore whats the best practice

Tags: asp.net-core

im not sure what im doing is the best practice or if its not what should i do ,in .net core you register your services and then inject it in a controller you want right?now if i have to inject 3 services in my controller or lets say n services ,i should pass n parameters in my constructor,but is not it too much?

here is my controller :

```
 public class AcessInfoController : ControllerBase
{
    // private DbContextClass db;
    private IAccessInfo _acess;
  public  AcessInfoController(IAccessInfo access)
    {
        _acess = access;

       // db = context;

    }
```

now i need to inject another IAnotherInterface ,whats the best practice to make it more readable?

Comment: What is the problem in adding the `IAnotherInterface` argument to your constructor? Do you get any exceptions/error messages?

Comment: @Progman its not a problem but im asking its the right way?adding multiple Interfaces in my constructor ? because if you need to add let's say 5 other services in this constructor then becomes less readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with best-practice...

If you have multiple services doing different stuff and you need them in a controller the way to inject them is as follows:

```
public class AcessInfoController : ControllerBase
{
    private IAccessInfo _access;
    private IAnotherInterface  _another;
    private IAndAnotherInterface  _andAnother;

    public AcessInfoController(IAccessInfo access, IAnotherInterface another, IAndAnotherInterface andAnother)
    {
        _access = access;
        _another = another;
        _andAnother = andAnother;
    }
```

Of course your `ctor`-line may be a bit longer but that is not an issue.

What would be the alternative?
You could wrap your three interfaces in a forth one. But why?